Change working directory in zsh widget?
I try to map C-z to call zoxide jumping to recently working directory, however, zsh widget zle execute the function in subshell instead of interactively in current shell. Is there a way to change the working directory when using zle?
zoxide-jump () {
  # Assign the result of zoxide and fzf to a variable
  local dir="$(zoxide query --list | fzf --height 40% --reverse)"
  # Check if the directory string is non-empty
  [[ -n "$dir" ]] && cd "$dir"
  [[ -n "$dir" ]] && echo "cd $dir" || echo "No dirrectory selected"
}
# autoload -U zoxide-jump
zle -N zoxide-jump
bindkey '^z' zoxide-jump



UPDATE:
add zle accept-line solve my issue.
zoxide-jump () {
  # Assign the result of zoxide and fzf to a variable
  local dir="$(zoxide query --list | fzf --height 40% --reverse)"
  # Check if the directory string is non-empty
  [[ -n "$dir" ]] && cd "$dir"
  [[ -n "$dir" ]] && echo "cd $dir" || echo "No dirrectory selected"
  zle accept-line
}
# autoload -U zoxide-jump
zle -N zoxide-jump
bindkey '^z' zoxide-jump


Something else must be the culprit. Please try to construct a minimal working example. (Your code seems to miss some upper lines.) This changes the working directory successfully: gohome() { cd "$HOME"; zle reset-prompt }; zle -N gohome; bindkey '^z' gohome. Note the zle reset-prompt to redraw the prompt after directory changing.
